# WPF Checkbox IsChecked and Checked not working together

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I want to bind a checkbox so if it was checked it should execute a code so I use Checked="Function". The problem is that I need to set the checkBox to Checked so I use IsChecked="True". If I do that a NullReferenceException is thrown.

If I remove that checkBox it also throws a NullReferenceException at a scrollBar:

```
<ScrollBar Maximum="10" Minimum="1" Value="2" name="Tol" ValueChanged="Tol_ValueChanged" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139"/>
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Did you look at the stack trace of the exception to see where it's being thrown?

Comment: @jmcilhinney okay thank you. I am offically to stupid to program. Thank you!